# sshd_config: AllowUsers is allowing unauthorized users

Tags: linux, sshd

So I've a VM that has SSH login. In this machine I only want one user ( lets say **admin**) to be able to login in via SSH.

Ive changed the ***`sshd_config`*** and added the *`AllowUsers admin`* directive. The problem is that I can still login to the machine with the user ***user***, for example.

The host is a Ubuntu server and I'm accessing it via vSphere Client.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Sry, but did you restart the ssh-daemon, after having applied the changes to the configuration file?

Comment: Hi. Yes after the changes ive applied the service ssh restart command.

Comment: it works for me fine with latest Ubuntu and Fedora.